# SELECT query failing when I added a WHERE statement in it

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I had a `SELECT` query like this at first..

```
($con,"SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1");
```

But, I realized that I needed the newest user out of the groups 2, 3, 4, or 5 (excluding group 1). So in the end I only want one user showing that is the newest.

What is wrong with my SELECT query now that it would not show up anything?

```
//Newest Member
$member = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE `group`=2, 3, 4,5 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1");
$numrows_member = mysqli_num_rows($member);
    if($numrows_member > 0){
        while($row_member = mysqli_fetch_assoc($member)){
            $memberid = $row_member['id'];
            $member_username = $row_member['username'];
            echo $member_username;
        }
    } else {
    echo "No Members Found...";
    }
```

Comment: You may want to use either `IN()` or `FIND_IN_SET()`. what exactly do you want to check for with 2,3,4,5 ? or, use `OR`'s.

Comment: In my users table I have a column called group. It is a permission system  I have. What I am doing with my code is finding the newest member of the site. With that said, group #1 is not allowed to view the site yet or granted a member yet until the group# is moved to 2 or above.

Comment: If you are looking for the latest user, you may want to consider ordering in descending order.

Comment: an answer's been posted using the same as my comment, `IN()`.

Comment: in that case you may want to just do `WHERE group != 1`

Comment: Dang, I like @DrewJordan's idea a lot better now. The `IN()` however may  be more flexible, if you ever would like to exclude certain groups again in the future. If you wanted to do it that way, you can use `WHERE group NOT IN(1, 6)` or something like that.

Comment: @DrewJordan agreed and worthy as an answer ;-)

Comment: After I have changed my SQL, I'm getting this error... `Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given` for this line `$numrows_member = mysqli_num_rows($member);`

Comment: make sure you're still escaping the column name, I forgot that in my comment. `group` is a reserved keyword. You're probably getting `FALSE` as a result because the query is failing

Comment: what is the column type for the group? @Paul

Comment: Paul, you also need to tell us if your rows have different values, rather than comma seperated values in your row(s). Do they have 1 or 2 or 3 etc, or are the rows like `1,2,3,4,5`? I'm leaning more towards seperated numbers and make sure that the column is `int` and not VARCHAR. That's what I make of this. Please respond to comments given and check @DrewJordan 's answer. I think that's the solution here.

Comment: The issue was not having the ``'s around the group column. I did `group` and it worked. Thanks @DrewJordan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the IN operator. The syntax would be like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE `group` IN (2, 3, 4, 5)
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

There is a [reference here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp).

Note: Based on your comment, if you are looking for the latest user you may want to order in `DESC` order instead, so that the largest id is put first. Even better (in my opinion), if you store the `account_created_date` you could order by that. Again, in descending order.

Comment: After I have changed my SQL, I'm getting this error... `Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given` for this line `$numrows_member = mysqli_num_rows($member);`

Comment: @Paul have you added backticks to `group`? That may be a reserved word, not sure if it would cause your error though. I don't have a lot of experience in PHP, so I'm not sure.

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to exclude a specific `group`, use `!=` instead of trying to find one of the remaining groups:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE `group` != 1 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I think the OP's rows contain seperate values instead of having comma seperated numbers/values, so I feel this is the solution. The OP is not responding to comments and I think the column's type may not be `int`. That's what I make of it at this point.